# Am I able to hide the GNOME title bar for applications?

Tags: linux, centos, fedora, gnome

I've forgotten if this is even possible. I have been using another OS and it's gotten me use to *not* seeing the OS's title bar on applications. Is it possible to hide it when using GNOME? I am on CentOS Stream 9, similar to Fedora/RHEL-9.

I attached a couple of examples.

[image: example #1]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

[image: example #2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plainly, *applications* can be run full screen, *sans* title bar, as do some video and image apps, so it is possible if the *app* implements it.

See the [Unite GNOME shell extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1287/unite/) which, among other things,

- Removes titlebars on maximized windows.
- Hides window controls on maximized windows with headerbars.

Download [from GitHub](https://github.com/hardpixel/unite-shell).

Please let us know if this works for you.

Comment: I installed via the https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1287/unite/ It's perfect and more. It's actually an improvement for my VS Code app. Thanks!